# What will be wave function after application of operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, wavefunction-collapse

In the mathematical treatment of quantum mechanics, we have a wave function ($ψ$) that helps us to know the different information (like position, velocity, energy, etc.). To measure such a quantity we use operators. Let us drive down to the real situation where we are measuring the position of a particle (say electron traveling in a straight line), to do so we send a beam of light toward the path of the electron (perpendicular to the path), and if it strikes or interacts with electrons in its path, it will get scattered to a detector and we get to know its position at that particular instant of time, but because of its interaction with light  its wave function will change, so is that changed wave function is given by the operation of old wave function with position operator $X̂$  ($X̂|ψ>$) ? and similarly we will find wave functions after measurement of other different quantities to be different, is that true?

[image]

Comment: Related: [Can an operator acting on a wave function be equal to taking a measurement?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/734499/can-an-operator-acting-on-a-wave-function-be-equal-to-taking-a-measurement)

Answer (score 1):

No, the state vector after a position measurement is *not* given by $X |\psi\rangle$.

Suppose your detector can decide whether the position of the particle is inside oder outside a certain (space) interval $I=[x_1,x_2]$. The *projection operator* for the particle to be found in $I$ is thus given by $$P_I=\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} \! \! dx |x\rangle \langle x |,$$ where $X|x\rangle = x |x\rangle$,  $\langle x| x^\prime \rangle=\delta(x-x^\prime)$ and $P_I^2=P_I=P_I^\dagger$. If the position $x$ of the particle, initially prepared in the state $|\psi\rangle$, is found in the interval $I$, the state $|\phi \rangle$  *after* the measurement is given by $$ |\phi \rangle = \frac{P_I |\psi\rangle}{||P_I |\psi\rangle||}$$ (projection postulate) with the corresponding wave function $$\phi(x)=  \langle x | \phi \rangle =\frac{\psi(x) \, c_I(x)}{\sqrt{\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} \! \! dx^\prime |\psi(x^\prime) |^2}},
$$ where $$c_I(x)= \begin{cases} 1 \;\text{for} \;x \in I \\[5pt]0 \;\text{for}\; x\notin I  \end{cases}$$ is the characteristic function of the interval $I$.

In the case where the particle is found *outside* the interval $I$, the corresponding projection operator is given by $$P_{\,\mathbb{R} \setminus I}= \int\limits_{\mathbb{R} \setminus I}\! \! dx  |x \rangle \langle x| = \mathbb{1}-P_I,$$ with all other steps performed analogously.